# Force div's background-image fetch it's size

Tags: html, css, background, size, fetch

I've got a **div** which absolutely needs an **auto width** that depends on text length inside it. I want a blue halo showing off as background image of that button when I hover it with my mouse.

**But here's the challenge I can't solve:** I want that blue halo png image to fetch the exact width of the div, I want a real distortion of the halo image without respecting any proportion.

How can I accomplish this without giving an absolute value for the width of the div? **And without using anything more than HTML and CSS3?**

***HTML side:***

```
<div class="button">
  <p>Hover here!</p>
</div>
```

***CSS side:***

```
.button {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 81px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button:hover {
  background: url("http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/300291bluehalo.png") center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ynwsmkrz/5/**

Comment: you can add background-size:cover; to the image and then whatever be the size of the div it will cover it

Comment: Have you considered using css for the gradient rather than an image? It would load faster.

Comment: Well, I've tried both container and cover and even custom values, but this is what I obtain: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/625094situation1.jpg and this is what I'm searching for: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/412909situation2.jpg

Comment: @mlegg: well gradient is not what I'm looking for as I really want a "halo" effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have to do is add a `background-size: cover;` to the `.button:hover` like this:

**CSS:**

```
.button {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 81px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button:hover {
  background: url("http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/300291bluehalo.png") center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It makes the background image cover the whole div, without cropping it. Hopefully my answer was helpful!

Comment: Well, I've tried both container and cover and even custom values, but this is what I obtain: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/625094situation1.jpg and this is what I'm searching for: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/412909situation2.jpg

Comment: Use background-size: 100% height-of-container; In your fiddle this would be: background-size 100% 100px; (If I understand correctly what you are trying to do)